# Lagged regression in cross sectional data (by year)

Tags: r, time-series, lag

I have a cross-sectional dataset with columns: YEARS, IRR, MSCI, GDP. Year column includes duplicated years.

I want to regress the following lagged regression using R:

```
IRR (on a certain year t) = MSCI (t-1) + GDP (t+2)
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to create lagged regression when we only have a year column (not month or day where I could differentiate). Furthermore, in my case xts or ts will not work since I cannot consider the year column as time series. Indeed I have tried to create the xts object and the lag solely using the xts object: `lag(t, k=1:3, na.pad=T)` but I don't think this is correct since I receive the following result:

[xts object of the year solely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE22D.png)

To give you an idea on my type of data:

```
dput(restr_subs[1:20, c(7:10)])
structure(list(vintage_year = c(1994, 1997, 1999, 2003, 2006, 
2010, 1996, 1997, 2013, 2008, 2011, 2008, 2003, 2008, 2008, 1993, 
1997, 2005, 2008, 2012), msci = c(967.178, 1123.85, 1659.94, 
1238.275, 2005.462, 1662.765, 1115.703, 1123.85, 1882.765, 1207.908, 
1417.102, 1207.908, 1238.275, 1207.908, 1207.908, 914.086, 1123.85, 
1631.352, 1207.908, 1598.55), gdp_growth_euro = c(2.45535801109142, 
2.71170595673225, 2.97399920715569, 0.702077716039668, 3.22619349743456, 
2.13778382809961, 1.69840302438114, 2.71170595673225, -0.240938104543716, 
0.421737450352921, 1.66931311921763, 0.421737450352921, 0.702077716039668, 
0.421737450352921, 0.421737450352921, -0.666275683950801, 2.71170595673225, 
1.68884368777726, 0.421737450352921, -0.885538224440225), gdp_growth_america = c(4.02723407999565, 
4.44728585240242, 4.68421663293515, 2.94608259760672, 2.97554787280134, 
2.61257308216338, 3.77196199460023, 4.44728585240242, 1.88921218426674, 
-0.027224507441403, 1.70407509983048, -0.027224507441403, 2.94608259760672, 
-0.027224507441403, -0.027224507441403, 2.75296371468099, 4.44728585240242, 
3.64575623821824, -0.027224507441403, 2.19858369375321)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fb3408122e0>)
```

Comment: Hi, could you attach your data to your question using `?dput()`

Comment: Hi, yes, just added it. Thank you for your help @OttoKässi

Comment: `dput` cannot be used on a data table since such objects include a pointer and they cannot be reproduced.  If `X` is the data table shown in the question then please show the output of `dput(as.data.frame(X))`

Comment: Hope everything is fine now!

Answer (score 0):

xts does not support just numeric years as times but zoo class and zooreg class in the zoo package and ts class in base R all support this.

Create a zooreg object, say, using only year and then run `dyn$lm` which will ensure alignment.

This also works with ts as shown below.

```
library(dyn) # also pulls in zoo

set.seed(123)
z <- zooreg(cbind(IRR = rnorm(10), MSCI = rnorm(10), GDP = rnorm(10)), 1997)

fo <- IRR ~ lag(MSCI, -1) + lag(GDP, 2)  
fm.z <- dyn$lm(fo, z)  # using zooreg
fm.ts <- dyn$lm(fo, as.ts(z))  # or using ts
```

Compare `z` and `model.frame(fo, z)` to understand the model.

This also works with the dynlm package.

```
library(dynlm)

fo2 <- IRR ~ L(MSCI) + L(GDP, -2)  
fm2.z <- dynlm(fo2, z)  # using zooreg
fm2.ts <- dynlm(fo2, as.ts(z))  # or using ts
```

Comment: This would be definitely a nice starting point, the problem is that I would still have the same issues regarding the duplicated years. In fact, I have to consider all the years (including the duplicates) in order to perform the lagged regressions. Any idea on how should I deal with duplicate years in the time series? @G.Grothendieck